# How do I write a program that replies to user input? (Python)

Tags: python

Im quite a beginner at python. I am doing a Grok course and I am stuck on this problem. Its asks you to 'Write a program that asks the user when it rained this week, and then tells them how many days were rain free.'

Interaction should look like this: 
Which days had rain? Monday Tuesday Wednesday
Number of days without rain: 4

I just don't know how to write it. If anybody could write or simple version or something and let me build on it that would be great. I am interested in Python but I also just wanna pass school. I have tried heaps of different code and have been stuck for days. 
Thanks

I have this now:

```
day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday',                Sunday]
days = input("Which days had rain? ")
count = 0
days_no_rain = print("Number of days without rain:", + len(day) + count)
days_as_num = len(days.split())
days_with_rain = 7 - days_as_num
```

I also realise that might be nothing like the code I need.

Comment: Go talk to your teacher.  **Now.**  You have an issue with the way that the material is being taught that only interaction with them can solve.

Comment: What have you come up with so far? You won't get much help on here without showing some input from your own efforts.

Answer (score 2):

try to start with this:

```
>>> b = raw_input('a?')
a?B C D
>>> print b
B C D
>>> print b.split()
['B', 'C', 'D']
>>> print len(b.split())
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example of taking inputs for days it has rained. Also note in this example it does not test if the day is a valid day. I have set up a sentinel controlled loop that you enter a day of the week it has rained, and then enter -1 when you are finished. Since their is seven days in a week, once we have entered all of ours days, we subtract seven by the number of days it has rained to get our answer of how many days it has not rained this week.

```
count = 0

x = raw_input("Enter a day of the week that it has rained(-1 to quit) ::")
while x != "-1":
    count += 1
    x = raw_input("Enter a day of the week that it has rained(-1 to quit) ::")

print "It has not rained :: ", 7 - count, "days this week"
```

Comment: Ok i will try and work with this, thanks